# Dynamically print alternative string character from two different string

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, codeigniter

I'm trying to print alternative character form two different string dynamically. I did below code but it's give me "TrAaUuSt" this output. but I want "TrAaUuStIF". How can I solve this? Anyone can help me? Thank You in advance. I'm new in PHP. If you have better solution then please suggest me.

```
<?php

/*$str1 = "TAUSIF";
$str2 = "raut";
Output = TrAaUuSt*/


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $str1 = $_POST['str1'];
    $str2 = $_POST['str2'];

    $strlen1 = strlen($str1);
    $strlen2 = strlen($str2);


    if($strlen1 > $strlen2)
    { 
        for($i = 0; $i<$strlen2; $i++){         
            $new[] = $str1[$i];
            $new[] = $str2[$i];       
        }

    }
    else
    {
        for($i = 0; $i<$strlen1; $i++){ 
            $new[] = $str1[$i]; 
            $new[] = $str2[$i]; 
        }

    }

    foreach($new as $str){
        echo $str;
    }
}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Print alternative character.</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="str1" ><br><br>
       <input type="text" name="str2" ><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
    //$str1 = "TAUSIF";
    //$str2 = "raut";

    $str1 = $_POST['str1'];
    $str2 = $_POST['str2'];

    // SPLIT STRINGS TO ARRAY
    $a1 = str_split($str1);
    $a2 = str_split($str2);

    $out = ''; // THE OUTPUT STRING

    // CHECK WHICH STRING IS LONGEST
    $count = (count($a1) > count($a2)) ? count($a1) : count($a2);

    // LOOP BASED ON THE NUMBER OF CHARACTERS IN LONGEST STRING
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
        $out .= (isset($a1[$x])) ? $a1[$x] : '';
        $out .= (isset($a2[$x])) ? $a2[$x] : '';    
    }

    echo $out;  // TrAaUuStIF
}
```

NOTE:
If you need Unicode support, then you should consider making your own `str_split` function as described in the top voted comment here: http://php.net/str_split

Comment: Thank You #Michael K.. Its work. But can I print output with my code without error?

Comment: Glad it helped. Just add `isset($_POST['submit'])` as in your original post. I have updated the example now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*$str1 = "TAUSIF";
$str2 = "raut";
Output = TrAaUuSt*/


if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {   
$str1 = $_POST['str1'];
$str2 = $_POST['str2'];

$strlen1 = strlen($str1);
$strlen2 = strlen($str2);


if($strlen1 > $strlen2)
   { 
    for($i = 0; $i<$strlen2+$strlen1; $i++){         
            $new[] = $str1[$i];
            $new[] = $str2[$i];       
    }


   }else
    {
    for($i = 0; $i<$strlen1+$strlen2; $i++){ 
        $new[] = $str1[$i]; 
        $new[] = $str2[$i]; 
    }

}

foreach($new as $str){
    echo $str;
}
}
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Print alternative character.</title>
</head>
<body>

   <form action="" method="post">
       <input type="text" name="str1" ><br><br>
       <input type="text" name="str2" ><br><br>
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```